# How do I choose an application to start in c# with the Process control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, debugging, process

I've been looking at other posts to see how to make an app start in c#. I am making a app launcher and I added the process control. I wrote this code:

```cs
Process.FileName = "myapp.exe";
Process.Start();
```

I don't think this is the exact code but line 1 was the area I was getting an error. The error was that it could not find the file even though it was in the same directory.

My ide is visual studio 2019, I use .net framework 4.8 and .net core 5

Comment: Yes this does work very well, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to use the `ProcessStartInfo` class instead:

```
using (Process myProcess = new Process())
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;   
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.Start();
    // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself.
    // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it
    // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically
    // from this application using the Kill method.
}
```

Comment: I got my answer but I also tried this out and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow?view=net-5.0#examples